# Question about homomorphic image of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I did the following two questions.   I would like to know if my proofs are correct.  Also, I have a question about about meaning of some notations with respect to the first question.

> 1. Show that every homomorphic image of a field $F$ is isomorphic either to $F$ itself or to the zero ring.  (I am not sure if assuming homomorphic image means a function mapping all elements in its domain to its direct image is correct.)

Proof:  Let $F$ be a field and $f:F\rightarrow S$ be a surjective homomorphism from $F$ to $S$.  Let $I=ker f$ be an ideal of $F$.  $F$ is a field, so $I$ can only be either (a) $I=F$ or (b) $I=\{0_F\}$ 
If it is the case (a), where $I=F$   For any $x\in F$, $f(x)=0_S$  Then $f$ maps every elements from $F$ to the zero ring $\{0_S\}$
For case (b) $I=\{0_F\}$, then $f$ is injective since $ker f = 0_F$.  Along with $f$ being a homomorphic image from $F$ to $Im(f)$ then, $f$ is an isomorphism from $F$ to $Im(f)$.

> 2. If $F$ is a field, $R$ a nonzero ring, and $f:F\rightarrow R$ is a surjective homomorphism, prove that $f$ is an isomorphism.

Proof:  Let $f$ be the stated surjective homomorphism in the hypothesis.  Since $F$ is a field, then the only zero element in $F$ is the zero element and every nonzero elements in $F$ is a unit, so $F$ contains the identity element $1_F$.  $f$ being a surjective homomorphism implies that $f(0_F)=0_R$, so $ker f=0_F$, Also $f(a^{-1}a)=f(aa^{-1})=f(a)f(a)^{-1}=f(a)^{-1}f(a)=f(1_F)$ for all $a\in F$ and $a\neq 0$ which means any nonzero elements in $f(F)$ is not a zero divisor. Therefore $f$ is an isomorphic map from $F$ to $R$.

I have seen for question 1, in cases (a) that it could be formulated as $F/F\cong \{0_F\}$ and for case (b)  $F/\{0_F\}\cong F$.  I don't know what the two notations means $F/F$, $F/\{0_F\}$ in english.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Well yes every homomorphism from a field is either injective or trivial,  since the kernel is an ideal.  Apply the first isomorphism theorem for rings, to get either  $f(\mathbb F)\cong\mathbb F/\mathbb F\cong0$ or $R\supset f(\mathbb F)\cong\mathbb F/0\cong\mathbb F$.  So in the second case you have an embedding.

Comment: can I ask, are my two proofs correct?

Comment: I think they basically are.  Don't know that you need the stuff on divisors of zero, since you have an isomorphism.

Comment: In part $2$, I would just say, since $f$ is surjective, the kernel is trivial, so you have an isomorphism.

Comment: I use the no zero divisors to show that every nonzero elements in the field is maps to a nonzero elements and so only the zero element itself gets map to the zero element.  Thank you for checking them for me.